# Table beside a floating image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to accomplish something that I thought would be simple, but it seems that when it comes to CSS, you never know!

I have an image float to the left. Beside it, I have a title and under that title, but still besides the image, I want to display a table taking all the remaining width. In IE and Chrome, the table ends up under my image while in Firefox, it takes more that 100% (an horizontal scroll bar is displayed). Firefox gives a result closer to what I want, but I don't want the scrollbar.

Here some code that I tried to make work using w3school "try it" editor (http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1{
                font-size:1em;
            }
            img 
            {
                float:left;
            }
            .field{
                width:100%
            }    
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />
        <div class="content">
            <h1>this is the title</h1>
            <form>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="field"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

I know the structure is too complex for that simple form, but forms are automatically generated by a PHP script so I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a floated image taking horizontal space from the `.content` div is why you get the extended table. The `.content` div is not aware of the floated image width. You can offset this by placing a margin at least the width of the image on the `.content` div.

```
.content 
{
    margin-left: 95px; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbBLh/)

Comment: Well, the solution was simple after all! I did try a margin, but on the wrong element I guess or with a wrong combination! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `<table>` to `display: block` in the CSS and dropping the `width="100%"` attribute:

```
table {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dyxw7/

The above example includes a red border on the table so that you can see where it is, I also changed the image to a kitten to make sure it would show up.

Comment: Good sir, no longer do you need to go searching for a kitten to place into your code (though I do admire your dedication). I think you will appreciate the awesomeness of placekitten.com

Comment: The table is indeed displayed properly with your solution, but I need to have the text box fill the whole space too (I forgot to specify, sorry). Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The `.content` div is 100% of the page wide including the bit under the floated image so the input set at 100% is also going to be that wide, to make the `.content` div take up only the space that's left after the floating image you can add `overflow: hidden` to it, but then the `input` itself can use varying box models, so I would suggest using a width of 99% on it. If the content is not actually an `input` then maybe 100% will work for most elements ;)

e.g. x-browser-code

```
h1 {font-size:1em;}

table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
table td {padding: 0;}

.content {overflow: hidden;}
form {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

img {float:left;}

.field {
    width:99%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but adding a margin as suggested by Dustin Laine made it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to float your table along with your image and remove the width:100% on your table.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="side_bar" style="float:left;">image</div>
    <div id="main_content" style="float:left;">table</div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

or the old way

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>image</td>
        <td>table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```